# Cannot create form field for 'country' yet, because its related model 'address.Country' has not been loaded yet (when upgrading Django 1.8 to 1.9)

Tags: python, django, django-1.9, django-oscar

I'm developing a subscription site which includes a 'signup' app. I'm also using a django-oscar shop for one-off purchases and using its UserAddress classes across the whole site. However, as my address and username/email forms are on the same page at subscription signup I use a temporary custom ModelForm based on AbstractAddress with specific fields in signup/forms.py:

```
# signup/forms.py

from oscar.apps.address.abstract_models import AbstractAddress    

class CustomAddressForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        """
        Using AbstractAddress because UserAddress requires a User and there
        is none when signup form is displayed. A UserAddress instance is then 
        created later, using the User object created after request.POST.
        """
        model = AbstractAddress
        fields = ['line1', 'line2', 'line4', 'state', 'postcode', 'country']
```

With INSTALLED_APPS:

```
# settings.py

from oscar import get_core_apps

INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'signup',
...
] + get_core_apps()
```

It's all been working fine in Django 1.8 but I've just tried upgrading to 1.9 prior to deploying and I get the following error message:

```
File "path/to/python3.4/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 942, in formfield(self.name, self.remote_field.model))
Cannot create form field for 'country' yet, because its related model 'address.Country' has not been loaded yet
```

Presumably I could move my custom modelform into the django-oscar core but would rather not.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155379/django-valueerror-cannot-create-form-field-because-its-related-model-has-not-b) question but as the model in my case is called in the form's Meta fields list as the string 'country', I'm not sure how to import the `Country` model here.

I can't find any sign of ModelForms having changed in Django 1.9. Or does anyone know why my form would work in 1.8 but not 1.9?

Comment: I currently have the same error, did you manage to fix it?